# C++ Pointer to an array of enum

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've got a problem with trying to point to a vector and then setting the value of an element when trying to de-reference it.

```
std::vector < Maze::TILE_CONTENT> * theGrid;
if (go->team == GameObject::GT_BLUE)
    *theGrid = m_myGridBlue;
else
    *theGrid = m_myGridRed;

if (go->curr.y < m_noGrid - 1)
{
    theGrid[next.y * m_noGrid + next.x] = Maze::TILE_EMPTY; //no operate '=' matches these operands
}
```

Comment: When you work with pointers you need to understand what you are doing, You seem just tried to fix compile error mechanical way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here.  The first is in the assignment to `*theGrid`.  This code will copy the source vector to whatever `theGrid` points to.  Since that pointer is uninitialized, you have Undefined Behavior, a crash if you're lucky.  I think what you're trying to do is

```
theGrid = &m_myGridBlue;
```

The second problem, which gives your compilier error, is how you access the pointed-to vector.  Since `theGrid` is a pointer to a vector, you need to dereference that pointer first:

```
(*theGrid)[next.y * m_noGrid + next.x] = ...;
```

As an alternative to the pointer, you can use a reference

```
std::vector<Maze::TILE_CONTENT> &theGrid = go->team == GameObject::GT_BLUE ? m_myGridBlue : m_myGridRed;
```

then you can access the contents of `theGrid` as you already are.

Comment: Or `auto &theGrid = ...` would be even simpler